# How to check <input> tag is click or not?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a input tag like this :

```
<input type="file" id="excel_file"
accept=".csv, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel"
style="color:transparent; "/>
```

and the output:

[image]

What I trying to do is I want to check whether the `Choose File` button is clicked or not. I couldn't check with the same method like a normal button cause this `choose file` is not a button.
Does anyone know how can I detect if user is clicking it or not ?

Comment: You can detect if some file is selected or not instead, by checking the value change in it

Comment: @Rana Thanks for ur respond, do you mean by checking the filename ?

Comment: Yup if it is input value is empty or not

Comment: @Rana But what if i already upload a file then only select another one? In this case the value is not empty anymore.

Comment: Yes than that will catch the change in value of `input` . You can use `onchange` event listener to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to listen for the click event simply use the following:

```
const inputElement = document.getElementById('excel_file');
inputElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('I was clicked');
}, false);
```

However, if you want to listen for the event of a file selection then you should you use 'change' instead of 'click'. The 'change' event will only trigger when a file is selected avoiding triggering your function if a user clicks the button then exits by clicking on cancel.

For more information:
[Using files from web applications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications)